# Read app.json (or exp.json) programmatically

Tags: react-native, expo

Is there a way to read the contents of `app.json` programmatically from within you app, so you could for example get the current version number and show it within an *About* screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constants.manifest got deprecated now, you can access this through Constants.expoConfig. This includes your app.json config without any of the potentially sensitive information such as API secret keys.

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
Constants.expoConfig.version
```

Answer (score 66):

You can access this through `Constants.manifest`. This includes your *app.json* config without any of the potentially sensitive information such as API secret keys.

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
Constants.manifest.version
```

Comment: @brentvatne, how can we access version in expo SDK 33, coz I am facing the issue while getting the version.

Comment: how would you put google map api key in app.js ? I tried to add a googmapkey, it said invalid key

Comment: @Milean - I updated the code to switch over to using expo-constants

Comment: This does not work in SDK 46.

Answer (score 5):

For Expo SDK 35, I did this:

```
expo install expo-constants
```

in your .js:

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";

<Text> {Constants.manifest.description} </Text>
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Expo SDK 46, use `Constants.expoConfig`. Source: https://github.com/expo/expo/discussions/17176

Answer (score 3):

For expo SDK 33 use:

```
 import Constants from "expo-constants";
 {`v${Constants.manifest.version}`}
```

Answer (score 3):

npm:

```
npm install expo-constants
```

OR

expo:

```
expo install expo-constants
```

About.js

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";

<Text>Version {Constants.manifest.version} </Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of expo (I'm on 36) now import the variable differently

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
```

Read all about it [here on the expo documentation site](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants/)

Answer (score 0):

When trying to use this line

```
import { Constants } from 'expo-constants';
```

`Constants` was showing up as undefined when logged to the console.

However, this code worked to display the app's version:

```
<template>
  <text>version: {{ appVersion }}</text>
</template>

<script>

import * as Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      appVersion: Constants['default']['manifest']['version']
    }
  }
}
</script>
```